# Oauth.io only gets "name" and "id" in the raw data from Facebook v2.4 and v2.5

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth.io

When integrating a Facebook App with `oauth.io`, the latest API version we can choose is `v2.3`.

The login process works though, but, when trying to retrieve the user data (`/me`), only the elements `name` and `id` are being delivered in the raw data from the `oauth.io` response:

```
curl "https://oauth.io/auth/facebook/me" 
     -H  “oauthio:k=<myOauthKey>&access_token=<fbAccessToken>"
```

we get following response:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": 
    {
        "id": "fbId",
        "avatar": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/fbId/picture",
        "name": "User Name",
        "gender": 1,
        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/fbId",
        "raw": 
        {
            "name": "User Name",
            "id": "fbId"
        }
    }
}
```

If we make the call directly using Facebook, I can get extra fields if I specify them in the URL:

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?access_token=<fbAccessToken>
      &fields=name,email,gender,birthday,first_name,last_name,picture"
```

we get the data we are looking for:

```
{
   "name": "User Name",
   "email": "email\u0040email.com",
   "gender": "female",
   "birthday": "03/02/1994",
   "first_name": "User",
   "last_name": "Name",
   "picture": {
      "data": {
         "is_silhouette": false,
         "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xlt1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/whatever"
      }
   },
   "id": "fbId"
}
```

The reason is clear: since `v2.4` Facebook requires the `fields` parameter to retrieve the extra data. See **Fewer default fields for faster performance** under https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/07/08/graph-api-v2.4/

Do you know if there is any way to tell oauth.io to fill the `fields` parameter when calling the facebook `/me` call?

Btw, using:

```
https://oauth.io/auth/facebook/me?fields=name,email,gender,birthday
```

does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Oauth.io` has fixed the issue and is available from `1.0.0-beta.18`

https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd/commit/7beec64ab39955c3afd2eb28ecf7288c74ccdc96